# CRA PWA Service Worker not refreshing

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app, progressive-web-apps, service-worker

I have **create-react-app** app that uses its stock **service worker** to cache files.
I want the app to be a downloadable **PWA** but whenever I update (with heroku & node expressjs..) the users downloaded app never updates.. Even when I refresh (drag down from top).

Have I missed some configuration in the docs to enable the auto update when its a PWA?
**or**
What is something I can do to either force refresh when updated. (I have read that's bad UI but I'm fine with that)

Notes:
It works as expected when viewing from a browser on a PC. (updates when tabs are all closed)

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.

The problem wasn't refreshing the app. I had to permanently close it. by swiping up from the multitask view.

Leaving this here in case anyone else didn't realize